# Finding an item in an ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

In C#, finding an item in an ArrayList that have a certain property, it's quite easy:

```
mSelectedBoard = mBoardConnections.FirstOrDefault(bcd => bcd.Id == id);
```

This is the easiest I've found to do the same in Java (wish I could afford MonoTouch for android):

```
for ( BoardConnectionData bcd : mBoardConnections ) {
    if (bcd.getID() == id) {
      mSelectedBoard = bcd;
      break;
    }
}
```

Am I missing an easier way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Define a meaningful `equals` and use `Collection.contains`.</strike>

There are a number of utility libraries that contain implementations using various "am I it?" implementations. ([Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), [Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/), etc.)

Another option is to create a typed collection containing utility methods finding elements by arbitrary criteria.

In any case, the code snippet shown shouldn't live in the mainline code, it should be abstracted into its own method, regardless of where it ends up living.

Comment: Contains returns a boolean, the code of the poster returns the item with a given ID...

Comment: When you override `equals()`, make sure to override `hashCode()` as well, otherwise you might get in [trouble][1] later if you decide to use e.g. a `HashSet` as storage later. [1]:http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/why-always-override-hashcode-if-overriding-equals/20

Comment: Right. As for closures, there are several dynamic languages that run on the JVM. My preference for server-side is Groovy. From the mention of Android, I wonder if the runtime target is the Java subset for Android. I'm curious about Guava; it's a nice package of libraries, but it doesn't actually extend the language. When I get another opportunity to do Android development, I'll definitely look for dynamic languages, starting with testing the limits of Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to match a single property, and multiple items in the list can have identical values for that property, then you need to loop thru like you are doing.  Java has a `Collections` utility class with a bunch of static methods; it might make sense for you to define your own collections utility methods to handle cases like this.

In general though, if you wan't to find an element, just use [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) and be sure to implement `equals` properly.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no closures in Java, there's no really easier way to do it. Of course, you can use Guava, but IMHO it offers only a bit of conciseness for a lot of complexity (for your example, at last, because Guava is quite cool otherwise)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `BoardConnectionData` class correctly overrides the `equals` method based on the ID, the following should tell you if the object is in the list or not:

```
mBoardConnections.contains(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you inherit from `Comparable` to test for the id member and use a [SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html):

```
BoardConnectionData brd = 
sortedSet.tailSet(new BoardConnectionData(searchedId)).first();
```

It is not more efficient complexity-wise, but it is shorter code. :)

Answer (score 0):

To pile on to Dave Newton's answer. The `Collection` is an `ArrayList`, so with an appropriate `equals` (plus `hashCode`) implementation on `BoardConnectionData`, the `indexOf` method would allow the expression

```
selectedBoard = boardConnections.getAt(boardConnections.indexOf(new BoardConnectionData(id)))
```

Of course, it's likely preferable to construct a probe object rather than creating a full-blown instance from only the id.

Answer (score 0):

You really should ask your self if `ArrayList` is the right data structure. Given similar task, I would choose a `Map`. Both C# and Java will need O(N) to search in an array. Using a map is O(1). If this is something you need to often then I would suggest the right structure.

Really the only difference between the C# and Java version is that one is shorter and uses closure. As many other people have suggested, you can do the same thing with some existing libraries. No one actually showed any code though. With Guava, you can do:

```
Iterables.find(new Predicate<Data>(){
public boolean apply(Data d){
 return d.id == someId;
)}, list);
```

Or if you want a default value you can use [.find(predicate, list, defaultValue)](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#find%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate,%20T%29).

Comment: I'm pretty sure I don't want a Map, although it would do the job.  I iterate over the list in a few situations -- it's data that shows in the master-side of a listview for master/detail.  For most cases when I need a single object, I've gotten it from the .tag on the item in the listview.  I just hit this case when writing the code to restore my Fragment back from saved state, as I only want to save the id, rather than have to be able to write the entire object as a parcelable.  I do like the approach using equals(), though ... I think I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 you can do like this:

```
mSelectedBoard = mBoardConnections
    .stream().filter(bcd -> bcd.Id == id).findFirst().orElse(null);
```